# Space Click Not Registering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Note: All code is in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5qrkk/
I have this code to register spaces in Javascript

```
$(window).on("keydown", function(key){
    if(key==32){
        console.log("SPACE");
        $(".sh").fadeOut(600).toggleClass("hdt").toggleClass("sh");
        $(".hd").fadeIn(600).toggleClass("sht").toggleClass("hd");
        $(".sht").toggleClass("sh").toggleClass("sht");
        $(".hdt").toggleClass("hd").toggleClass("hdt");
    }
});
```

The content inside of the if loop makes the div with the class sh (which is shown) become hidden, and replace the class sh with hdt (rather than instantly going to hd because the old hd classes still need to be modified). The same thing happens with the div currently at the hd class (which starts hidden). None of these events, including the `console.log`, are happening when I click space. I also would like to avoid putting these in the `$(document).ready()` function as this might create errors as this changes the DOM and needs to be using the updated DOM each time it runs.

Comment: first argument of event handler is not `key` it is `event`. See docs regarding accessing key  http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function(key) {
   if(key==32){
```

Should look like

```
function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
```

The argument passed to the handler is the `event` object. 
keyCode is a property on that object which gives you the key that was pressed.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qrkk/1/)**